# How to refactor simple code in Pythonic way

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have following code. As you can see, my C++ roots are there. How do I refactor this, so that code looks more Pythonic? I'm not looking for a 1 liner; code needs to be easier to understand as well.

```
from collections import Counter 

def mostCommon(lst): 
  if not lst:
    raise Exception("Empty data list, expecting list of ints!")
  common = Counter(lst).most_common(len(lst))
  common_elements = []
  common_elements.append(common[0][0])

  #Get max frequency of reoccurence 
  max_freq = common[0][1]
  for i in range(1, len(common) ):
    if common[i][1] >= max_freq:
      common_elements.append(common[i][0])

  return common_elements


print(mostCommon(lst = [-8, 100, 5, -100, 7, 2, -8, 9, 6, 9, 9, -8, 8, 8, 8]) )
print(mostCommon([]) )
```

Comment: I suspect this belongs in SE Code Review.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with something like this:

```
def mostCommon(lst): 
  # handle empty case
  if not lst:
    return lst

  ctr = Counter(lst)
  max_count = max(ctr.values())
  return [k for k, v in ctr.items() if v == max_count]
```

If you want the empty list to throw the error, you can drop the lines before `ctr = Counter(lst)`. Note also that this does not need to sort the unique values, which means that the runtime is linear in size of `lst`.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I had code to handle the empty list.

Answer (score 1):

this is some little variation from @hilberts_drinking_problem, but based on his answer

```
from collections import Counter, defaultdict

def mostCommon(lst): 
    if not lst:
        return lst
    res = defaultdict(list)
    for k, v in Counter(lst).items():
        res[v].append(k)

    return res[max(res.keys())]
```

Comment: Good solution as well. But I have not used defaultdict before, not exactly sure how it works. I have used Counter.

Comment: @usustarr it just define that the value in the dictionary of acertain type  only (list in this case)